# Can one build a spacecraft containing an evacuated chamber on its exterior wall?

Tags: science-based, spaceships

Basically, the evacuated chamber is to perform some experiments. The spacecraft is of single stage to orbit variety. I am asking in terms of whether one can build it using generally used materials of construction like iron, etc.

Edit 1: The space for the vacuum chamber would be about 40 % of the space craft's volume, somewhat like an airship. the spacecraft should be able to evacuate the chamber on its own, even if it is on the surface of the earth, or any other planet with a dense atmosphere. It would probably be used to transfer stuff which would be air-sensitive, like alien bodies which were unaccustomed to oxygen gas.

Edit 2: The technological development of my species is the same as that of humans. An airlock big enough to contain many small space vehicles (in SF) (like an aircraft carrier carries planes) would be sufficient for my needs.

Edit 3:
Vacuuum as in [vacuum wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum#Pumping_and_ambient_air_pressure) 10−13 torr (13 pPa)

Comment: I'm not totally clear what you mean... obviously if you can get to orbit, you can just open a door and get all the vacuum you could want (more or less). Building vacuum chambers is straightfoward enough. Building an SSTO is pretty hard though, and you probably wouldn't be building much of it out of iron if you could use something lighter and more stable.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/86917/is-possible-to-make-an-almost-perfectly-sealed-ship ?

Comment: @StarfishPrime one can use aluminium, etc. I want a vacuum chamber inside the space ship, sharing a wall with the exterior hull of the spaceship. The spaceship is assumed to be a  SSTO  for simplicity.

Comment: @nzaman Unfortunately no since I don't have problem with the leaking air as such. I just want a chamber with can  be evacuated of all matter at will.

Comment: In which case, doesn't your argument just devolve to "_is it possible to make a vacuum chamber_?" (the answer is "yes") or "_is it possible to make an airlock with a vacuum pump_" (to which the answer is also just "yes"). Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: How is this different from an airlock?  Which nearly all spacecrafts have (if they want someone to be able to leave and/or return while in space).

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE Tejas, glad you found us.  Please check out our [tour] and [help].  We're pretty picky about questions here so please don't worry about all the comments.  Stick around, read, answer, and ask more questions if you wish.

Comment: @StarfishPrime,Thanks for the answer The chamber may cover a significantly large portion of the space craft. Would the answers still hold true?

Comment: Airlocks would generally be small @Cyn

Comment: Ok, it sounds like your question is basically about a spacecraft with a large-ish vacuum-filled cargo area? There are some structural issues there (it needs to contain a vacuum _and_ survive [max q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_q)) but thats just a Simple Matter Of Engineering to fix.

Comment: _All matter_ is thermodynamically impossible, you would need an infinite amount of energy to get a perfect vacuum; this is one of those situations, where you just have to say good enough at some point

Comment: @TejasShetty Could you please edit your question to specify your size requirements?  Is this the only difference from existing airlocks?  Would an airlock big enough to contain a small space vehicle (in SF) be sufficient for your needs?  Or are there other requirements?

Comment: I'll ask you to be more specific in your question: What do you mean by vacuum? What sized space? What is the level of technological development of your species? How is this about worldbuilding? Voting to put on hold as unclear, until the [edit].

Comment: @nzaman: Not so.  The space between atoms/molecules is a perfect vacuum.  All you need to do is to thin out the matter until the space between is as large as you want.

Comment: @jamesqf: And as I pointed out, that is thermodynamically impossible; you're arguing Maxwell's Demon

Comment: @nzaman: No, I'm not arguing with Maxwell's Demon, who doesn't enter here.  You are arguing with physics: if there are few atoms in a given space, then the places where the atoms aren't (of course neglecting the QM idea that every subatomic particle is somehow everywhere at once) is by definition a perfect vacuum.  Indeed, the only place I can think of where you wouldn't find some vacuum is in a neutron star.

Comment: @jamesqf: Yes, but the atoms are moving about within that space, so you cannot point arbitrarily at some point and say that volume is a perfect vacuum at this point in time. The best we can say is that an average that volume has an x% chance of being a vacuum, where x= (volume of molecule x estimated number of molecules in the enclosed space)/total volume of enclosed space. Which probably does lead back to QM

Comment: @Cyn Please see edit 2

Comment: @Chickensarenotcows please see edit 3

Comment: @TejasShetty I know what a vacuum is. I'm unclear what the specific worldbuilding issue is that you are having a problem with here. We've been able to make that level of vacuum since the 1980s, spaceships, we cracked that in the 1950s /1960s. I don't get what the actual problem is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: @TejasShetty, the answer to your question is: Yes, this is possible, and would not require any sort of special engineering, any sort of world building, or any sort of explaining away. Engineers might wonder why you'd have a giant airlock on your spaceship, but you're describing something that we've had since manned spaceflight started: A wall to keep air at 1atm pressure on one side of the hull, and 0atm on the other side.

Answer (score 4):

> the evacuated chamber is to perform some experiments. The spacecraft is of single stage to orbit variety. I am asking in terms of whether one can build it using generally used materials of construction like iron, etc.

A chamber with the intention to contain just vacuum when in operation and when it's surrounded by vacuum is quite trivial to construct.

You need a structure that *unfolds* when in orbit.  It can be completely flat when stowed during launch.  It can be stowed in a variety of folded forms.

As I assume you want a sealed region of vacuum, then you simply need a small aperture which can be closed after deployment.  A door, basically.  There are lots of ways to make a sealed door, and as pressure on both sides is the same there is no issue with having to resist a higher pressure on one side.

You would require an airlock of some wort to manage transfers between pressurized ship areas and the contained space, but that's pretty trivial.

If equipment needs to be deployed in the chamber you would store this during launch and deploy it from a dedicated cargo area, moving it to the contained space via the door.

Depending on precisely why you need it enclosed, the materials used could range from thin plastic to e.g. rigid hinged metal parts.